# Using this equation throws an error

Tags: math-mode, equations

```
    \begin{numcases}{C_{img}=}
load starting slice, if $S_{img}=>T$ \\
Process to end slice, End
\label{Eq:5.1} 
\end{numcases}
```

I need it to look like this

[image]

Comment: Do you want `C_{img}`?

Comment: Any particular error or does it just have a general moan about life? I think you would get an error with this. All documents need a `\documentclass` and code should be wrapped in a `document` environment.

Comment: @mins yes i get error missing} inserted . \begin{numcases}{C_{img}=}
load starting slice, if $S_{img}=>T$ \\
Process to end slice, End
\label{Eq:5.1} 
\end{numcases}

Comment: P.S.: For the nice code formatting, you should highlight the code and hit ctrl+k, or use the code sample button (it looks like {})

Comment: @Au101 can you plz run i have still problem because it give me error of missing} inserted

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Most likely you're missing some of the proper formatting for `numcases`. Note that `numcases` sets its contents in math mode already, so you should escape textual content using `\mbox` or (better yet) `\text` (from [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{numcases}{C_{\text{img}}=}
  \text{load starting slice}, & \text{if $S_{\text{img}} \rightarrow T$} \\
  \text{Process to end slice}, & \text{End}
\end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

The use of `&`'s are not necessary, but is typical of a *`cases` construction.

Comment: +1. I think the OP's screenshot indicated that he/she needs `\Rightarrow` rather than `\rightarrow` in the upper row.